# Calling self.private_method in Ruby not throwing error?

Tags: ruby

I thought that when calling a private method it was unacceptable to place a explicit receiver. Well I did this in Ruby 2.0 and I can get results:

```
class Test
  def public_method
    self.set_size=10
  end

  def return_size
    @size
  end

  private

  def set_size=(size)
    @size = size
  end

 end

test = Test.new
test.public_method
p test.return_size
```

Why is this?

Comment: Why did you think it's unacceptable? It looks acceptable to me.

Comment: Is not that I think, it's in the docs: ```Private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver - the receiver is always self. This means that private methods can be called only in the context of the current object; you cannot invoke another object's private methods.```

Comment: @HommerSmith: And you are calling the method on self... theres nothing wrong with this.

Comment: It's access restriction. Not syntax restriction. I would interpret it as "...cannot be called with an explicit receiver **other than self** as the receiver is always self"

Comment: @Linuxios Even with ```self``` would hung if it was not a setter method. An explicit receiver (self or whatever) is just correct if the method we are sending is a setter.

Answer (score 2):

Private setters *can* be called with an explicit receiver of `self`. In fact, they *have* to be called with an explicit receiver, because otherwise they couldn't be called at *all*, since

```
foo = bar
```

is an assignment to a local variable, not a method call.

Comment: I think what is needed is clarification that `set_size` is a method.  One way is to prepend `self.`; another is `send(:set_size=, 10)`, which does not have an explicit receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You are right except on one thing...setters (`def method=`) can be called with an explicit receiver of **self**, so that you can call private setters.

So, actually if you were about to do this:

```
class Test
  def public_method
    self.say_hi
  end

  def return_size
    @size
  end

  private

  def say_hi
    puts "oh hay there"
  end

 end
test = Test.new
test.public_method
test.return_size
```

It would throw a `private method say_hi called for..`